# CSV to object list

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack, servicestack-text

I am currently using ServiceStack.Text to de-serialize CSV to list of objects.

My Model

```
public class UploadDocument
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Patient")]
    public string Patient { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Patient First Name")]
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Patient Last Name")]
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

C# Code

```
var csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName).FromCsv<List<UploadDocument>>();
```

This works well even if any column missing in the CSV i.e if CSV contain only Patient, Patient First Name still it loads the data in object with null value for Patient Last Name and Email.

But it throws error when there is any extra column with no header

```
Patient,    Patient First Name, Patient Last Name,  Email
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwer@yahoo.com,      QWER
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwerwe@yahoo.com,    QWER
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwe@yahoo.com,       QWER
```

How do I handle this?

The expectation here is even if there is less number of columns or there is extra row without header, the matching column (CSV header and class property) should get loaded without any issues.

**Note:** The CSV column order will vary for every file

Comment: what error do you get? can you post more code like deserialize etc

Comment: @Gauravsa It throws value cannot be null

Comment: You should consider adding all columns to the dynamic list and add it one by one to your uploaddocument list

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried skipping the first line?

```
var results = csv.SubString(csv.IndexOf('\n')).FromCsv<List<UploadDocument>>();
```

> But it throws error when there is any **extra column with no header**

But as your CSV is invalid it's much better to fix your source `.csv` to ensure it contains the right number of headers as fields before you try to deserialize it, e.g:

```
var validCsv = csv.LeftPart('\n') + ",MissingName\n" + csv.RightPart('\n');
var results = validCsv.SubString(csv.IndexOf('\n')).FromCsv<List<UploadDocument>>();
```

Comment: var csvFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    var csvTempData = csvFile.Substring(csvFile.IndexOf('\n')).FromCsv<List<UploadDocument>>(); still it throws the same error value cannot be null

Comment: CSV creation is beyond my scope

Comment: @Gopi CSV is just a plain-text file containing Comma-Separated-Values on every line, I've updated my answer with an example of trying to fix it.

Comment: Still the same error, it looks like the MissingName should be there in Model class.